# Pandas long to wide

Tags: python, pandas, casting, melt

Using pandas, I want to convert a long data frame to wide but the usual `pivot` method is not as flexible as I need.

Here is the long data:

```
raw = {
'sample':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
'gene':['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G3', 'G1', 'G2', 'G2', 'G2', 'G3', 'G3'],
'type':['HIGH', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'MED', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'LOW', 'LOW', 'MED', 'LOW']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw)`
```

which produces

```
gene  sample  type
G1       1  HIGH
G2       1  HIGH
G3       1   LOW
G3       1   MED
G1       2  HIGH
G2       2   LOW
G2       3   LOW
G2       3   LOW
G3       3   MED
G3       3   LOW
```

What I want is a data frame that has rows as `gene` and columns as `sample`, but I want the cell value to be filled with the "greatest" `type` according to `HIGH` > `MED` > `LOW` > `NONE` i.e. it should look like

```
casted = {
'gene':['G1', 'G2', 'G3'],
'1':['HIGH', 'HIGH', 'MED'],
'2':['HIGH', 'LOW', 'NONE'],
'3':['NONE', 'LOW', 'MED']
}
dfCast = pd.DataFrame(casted)
```

which makes

```
1     2     3      gene
HIGH  HIGH  NONE   G1
HIGH  LOW   LOW    G2
MED   NONE  MED    G3
```

Trivially and erroneously, my long to wide command would look like

`df = df.pivot(index='gene', columns = 'sample', values='type')`

but of course this doesn't account for the hierarchy I want to impose where `HIGH`>`MED`>`LOW`>`NONE`

When casting, how can I control what the cell value is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table` which provides an `aggfun` method to aggregate duplicated index-column values; To sort the keywords `HIGH,MED,LOW` in an order you need, set them as keys of a dictionary whose values go in monotonic order, and pick the extreme value with `min/max` as the aggregation function:

```
cat = {"HIGH": 3, "MED": 2, "LOW": 1}
df.pivot_table("type", "gene", "sample", aggfunc=lambda x: max(x, key=cat.get))
```

[image]

---

Or another option, convert the *type* to ordered categorical data type and then use `pivot_table`:

```
df['type'] = pd.Categorical(df['type'], ["LOW", "MED", "HIGH"], ordered=True)
df.pivot_table("type", "gene", "sample", aggfunc='max')
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful and clean. Thank you!