# Pandas long to wide format with multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, reshape

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data.head()
Out[2]: 
        Area Area Id                  Variable Name Variable Id  Year  \
0  Argentina       9  Conservation agriculture area        4454  1982   
1  Argentina       9  Conservation agriculture area        4454  1987   
2  Argentina       9  Conservation agriculture area        4454  1992   
3  Argentina       9  Conservation agriculture area        4454  1997   
4  Argentina       9  Conservation agriculture area        4454  2002   
     Value Symbol Md  
0      2.0            
1      6.0            
2    500.0
```

That I would like to pivot so that `Variable Name` is the columns, `Area` and `Year` are the index and `Value` are the values. The most intuitive way to me is using:

```
data.pivot(index=['Area', 'Year'], columns='Variable Name', values='Value)
```

However I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-4c786386b703>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.concat(data_list).pivot(index=['Area', 'Year'], columns='Variable Name', values='Value')
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3853, in pivot
    return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py", line 377, in pivot
    index=MultiIndex.from_arrays([index, self[columns]]))
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 250, in __init__
    data = SingleBlockManager(data, index, fastpath=True)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4117, in __init__
    fastpath=True)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2719, in make_block
    return klass(values, ndim=ndim, fastpath=fastpath, placement=placement)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 1844, in __init__
    placement=placement, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 115, in __init__
    len(self.mgr_locs)))
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 119611, placement implies 2
```

How should I interpret this? I've also tried another way:

```
data.set_index(['Area', 'Variable Name', 'Year']).loc[:, 'Value'].unstack('Variable Name')
```

to try to get the same result, but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-222325ea01e1>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.concat(data_list).set_index(['Area', 'Variable Name', 'Year']).loc[:, 'Value'].unstack('Variable Name')
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2028, in unstack
    return unstack(self, level, fill_value)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py", line 458, in unstack
    fill_value=fill_value)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py", line 110, in __init__
    self._make_selectors()
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py", line 148, in _make_selectors
    raise ValueError('Index contains duplicate entries, '
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Is there something wrong with the data? I've confirmed that there are no duplicate combinations of `Area`, `Variable Name`, and `Year` in any row of the dataframe, so I don't think there should be any duplicate entries but I could be wrong. How can I convert from long to wide format given that both of these methods are not currently working? I've checked answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310781/pandas-long-to-wide) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310781/pandas-long-to-wide), but they are both cases where some type I aggregation is involved.

I've tried using `pivot_table` like so:

```
data.pivot_table(index=['Area', 'Year'], columns='Variable Name', values='Value')
```

but I think some type of aggregation is being done and there are a lot of missing values in the dataset which leads to this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-7-77b28d2f0dbb>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.concat(data_list).pivot_table(index=['Area', 'Year'], columns='Variable Name', values='Value')
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 136, in pivot_table
    agged = grouped.agg(aggfunc)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 4036, in aggregate
    return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 3468, in aggregate
    result, how = self._aggregate(arg, _level=_level, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 435, in _aggregate
    **kwargs), None
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 391, in _try_aggregate_string_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 1037, in mean
    return self._cython_agg_general('mean', **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 3354, in _cython_agg_general
    how, alt=alt, numeric_only=numeric_only)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 3425, in _cython_agg_blocks
    raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Comment: What about `data.pivot_table(index=['Area', 'Year'], columns='Variable Name', values='Value)` ?

Comment: I forgot to mention I've also tried this method and got another error. I think it has to do with some type of aggregation being done with missing values in the dataset. Editing question

Comment: Edited answer. There is problem your data are not numeric.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need first convert column `Value` to numeric  and then use `pivot_table` with default aggregate function `mean`:

```
#if all float data saved as strings
data['Value'] = data['Value'].astype(float)
#if some bad data like strings and first method return value error
data['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(data['Value'], errors='coerce')
```

---

```
data.pivot_table(index=['Area', 'Year'], columns='Variable Name', values='Value')
```

Or:

```
data.groupby(['Area', 'Variable Name', 'Year'])[ 'Value'].mean().unstack('Variable Name')
```

Comment: Ahhh, now this makes sense! I tried converting to float and I got `ValueError: could not convert string to float`. Looks like I should take a minute to clean the data a bit first and come back.

Comment: I add another solution.